# ReactJS setState doesn't work with a parameter/argument from a method/function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I can't seem to get setState to change (mutate) a value coming from an argument or parameter of a method/function. At least, it doesn't work on the first call. I have to call setState twice before the value changes.

```
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      testItem: 'originalValue'
    }
  }

  updateState(input) {
    this.setState({
      testItem: input
    },
      console.log(this.state.testItem) // displays 'originalValue' instead of 'newValue!', at least on the first call
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.updateState('newValue!')}>
        Change State
        </button>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The state of 'testItem' should change from 'originalValue' to 'newValue!' (taken from the argument 'input' in the method 'updateState(input)') when the button is clicked, but it doesn't change on the first click (even when using a callback in setState). It only changes when I click on the button a second time. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `console.log` gets invoked straight away with the current state, which is the initial state you set because `setState` is asynchronous (i.e state is not immediately updated with the latest change).

Because of this, we need to defer the invocation of `console.log` by wrapping it in a function. We do this so it can be invoked at a later time by the `setState` as opposed to every time you call `setState`

To do this, you pass a callback function that will be executed after your `setState` has been performed.

```
this.setState({ testItem: input}, () => console.log(this.state))
```

Comment: Agh, forgot the () => in the callback! Newbie error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ha, No problem, if I answered your question, please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

> This is happening because setState is asynchronous. You could use a
>   callback or async-await. A callback solution is already given. I would
>   like to give the solution with async-await -

```
async updateState(input) {
    await this.setState({
      testItem: input
    });
    console.log(this.state.testItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer to supplement the callback solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because before updating the state, `console.log(this.state.testItem)` has been run. As `setState` is asynchronous in nature. In order to avoid it:

1. Hack solution - use `setTimeout` (wait till it update)

```
   updateState(input) {
    this.setState({
      testItem: input
    });
    setTimeOut (() => {
      console.log(this.state.testItem)
    }) 
  }
```

2. Preferred way - Pass a callback as second parameter

```
   updateState(input) {
    this.setState({
      testItem: input
    }, () => console.log(this.state.testItem))
   }
```